# In Settlers of Catan: Explorers and Pirates, who gets the gold when the pirate is paid?

Tags: catan

In SoC: E&P, one can pay the pirate gold in order to move one's ships. Who receives that gold? The pirate owner or the bank?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Explorers and Pirates rules](http://www.catan.com/down/?/files/downloads/ep_overviewrules.pdf) under the *Paying Tribute to the Pirate* section (page 11):

> The tribute costs 1 gold, and you pay it to the supply.

From earlier in the rules, in the *Preparation* section (page 6):

> Place the resource cards and dice from the base *Catan* game beside the game board to form a supply area.

So it is paid to the supply, which is commonly referred to as the bank.